# HTML button that runs some MySQL code then opens a link

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I was put in the sin-bin for a week after my last question, so if anyone has problems with this one, please let me know first and I'll do my best to clear things up before I get put on hold.

Anyway, on to my problem:

I have a page that has a text box for a reference number. What I want is to run a mysql query that will check if that value exists on a table, if it doesn't, create a new line for it. I don't think I'll have too much trouble with this, I've managed to get the code to write to the table (although, at the moment that's regardless of whether it exists or not).

What's really got me stumped is how do I include their entered reference in a URL that should load after the query has been completed. Would I need to somehow pass something from the PHP to javascript?

The intended URL will be something along the lines of
www.foo.com/bar?=**REF** <--ref being the user-entered value.

As requested, the code I've used so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Application Form Prototype</title>

</head>

<hr width="100%" STYLE="position:absolute; top:220px">
<!--Breadcrumb Text-->
<hr width="100%" STYLE="position:absolute; top:260px">
<body>
<div style="position: absolute; TOP: 300px; left:100px; width: 75%">
<h1 class="heading-xlarge" style="Padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-top: 30px">Welcome to the prototype for the application form</h1>
<p class="lede">Please be aware that this prototype is <b>not</b> secure and as such, please enter only non-sensitive, non-personal data</p>
<p class="lede">Pleae enter a memorable reference for your application in the box below. If you are returning to a previous session, please enter the reference you assigned at that point</p>
<h1></h1>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Reference</label>
    <input type="text" name="ref" id="ref" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter reference"/><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit" /><br />
</form>

<?php
if(array_key_exists('ref', $_POST)) {
    include 'connection.php';
    $ref = $_POST['ref'];
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'INSERT INTO answers (strRef) VALUES (\'' .$ref . '\');');
}
?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I did try a bit of javascript, but calling an onclick event seemed to bypass my php, is that right? or was my DB just playing up?

Comment: The "Sin Bin" hey? The question, as it stands with no code and a vague description of what you want, is too broad or off-topic. Add the code you have to indicate where things are going astray would be better

Comment: AJAX the contents of the input to a PHP function to do the mechanics. If the value exists return it to the JavaScript that does a redirect with the returned value in the GET vars. Next time include some code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?php
if(array_key_exists('ref', $_POST)) {
    include 'connection.php';
    $ref = $_POST['ref'];
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'INSERT INTO answers (strRef) VALUES (\'' .$ref . '\');');
}

header('Location: http://foo.com/bar?=REF'.$ref.');
?>
```

try something like this

Comment: no problem your welcome

Comment: perhaps worth nothing - unless you are using output buffering and this snippet of php is located after the form ( as in the question ) you are likely to get errors warning about `headers already sent` so it should be placed at the top of the script before any html content is written.

Comment: yes its true i didn't care about it but your right dude